# Android touch events when screen is dark(ish)?

Tags: android, screen, touch-event

I've got a Samsung Galaxy Tab, which likes to dim the light on the device after about half a minute. When I touch the screen, it turns on the light again, but it also sends the touch event to whatever view is located where I touched, so I end up clicking on something I didn't mean to click.

Is there any way to know that the screen has dimmed the lights, so the touch events shouldn't be sent through to the views?

Update:
I use the flag keep_screen_on for each activity, but I don't really want to. Auto-dimming restrains battery use, so if it's possible I'd like to do something else.

Comment: On my HTC Hero it's the same thing - maybe this is an Android "bug"? (I would call this a bug...) On an iPhone I am sure that whenever the background light is dimmed nothing happens except the light goes on again...

Comment: found a solution ?!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the current Brightness Setting from here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS

I found this to be quite annoying as well, but I don't know if it should be the App's Job to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, but if someone were to set their screen brightness to something ridiculous themselves, I don't want to kill their eyes.